# Delay an iFrame from loading its src until a function is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple iFrames which are populated with sources dynamically.
The page is quite slow because so many iframes are loading at once so I would like to prevent them from loading until a certain event occurs (like a button next to each frame being pressed).

I considered a hack where I store the source into its name field and then use javascript to set the source equal to the name on button press. I don't know if this would work and it seems like a dirty hack anyway. There must be a better solution?

Comment: You could store the source instead in a `data-` attribute, like `data-src="whatever"`

Comment: Unfortunately my program has to work with older versions of IE which I don't think will support data-

Comment: You could chain the iframes loading by using the `when` `then` methods of jquery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: @user1636130 I think that data will work for older browsers when using jQuery, but you can always test to be sure.

Comment: data- does seem to work in a few of the older browsers. Going to go and test some more now but its looking very promising! Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery in order to build up the markup aync (speaking when an event occurs).

For example:

you have a div-container `<div id"myDiv"></div>`

You can use a jquery-selector to get this div:

```
var myDiv = $('#myDiv');
```

Once you have this accessible, you can dynamically put content to it.

```
var myIFrame = $('<iFrame></iFrame>');
myIFrame.attr("src", "http://myFavouriteSite.com");
```

When you build a function around this, you can call this function on a button click:

```
function renderAnIFrame{
  var myDiv = $('#myDiv'); //get selector

  var myIFrame = $('<iFrame></iFrame>'); //dynamicly construct an iFrame
  myIFrame.attr("src", "http://myFavouriteSite.com"); // add sourc-attribute to iFrame

  myDiv.append(myIFrame); //Interlace iFrame into Div-Container
}
```

All this happens, on a button-click-event with use of document-ready:

```
    <button type="button" id="btn-render-iFrame">
     </button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-render-iFrame').click(function () {
        renderAnIFrame ();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this mockup. I use the methods `when` and `then`. The iframes will be loaded in chain after the previous is loaded.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WNTyV/1/)

```
<iframe id="iframe1" /><br/><br/>
<iframe id="iframe2" /><br/><br/>
<iframe id="iframe3" /><br/><br/>

function loadIframe(iframe){
   $('#'+iframe).attr('src', 'jsfiddle.net');
   alert(iframe + ' loaded');
}

 $.when(loadIframe('iframe1'))
   .then(loadIframe('iframe2'))
   .then(loadIframe('iframe3'));
```